# A sequence of integers

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

Here is my sequence (finite):

> 19,499,12991,337787,8782467,228344156,5936948059,154360649539.

You just have to figure out its logic.

**Hint:**

> It is a "sequence" and I like alphabets.

Comment: I thought about adding a sequence tag, but we don't have one that is generic. I will leave it off, assuming that either 1) none of the individual tags match your puzzle, or 2) tagging as such would be a dead give-away

Comment: This is such a simple idea - I'm amazed nobody's posted a puzzle like this before! +1 and kudos to you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For ADG1, the logic is:

> Convert all of the numbers to base 26, and convert each place in each number using A = 1, B = 2, etc. ADG1 then becomes
>  
>  S, SE, SEQ, SEQU, SEQUE, SEQUEN, SEQUENC, SEQUENCE

Comment: maybe the hint is too helping.

Comment: @ADG Yeah, I admit I don't think I'd have approached it the way I did without the hint, and with the hint it kinda fell into place for me.

Comment: @ADG The hint seemed right to me, Dennis just did a great job of solving.